# Can't use 2 interfaces at the same time

Tags: linux, debian, networking, route

I can't get eth0 and usb0 (same with wlan0) working at the same.
When I activated the Android Tethering, I did `route add default gw 192.168.42.129 usb0`, and so, `route -n` outputs:

```
Table de routage IP du noyau
Destination     Passerelle      Genmask         Indic Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 usb0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 usb0
```

To test this, I did:

`curl --interface eth0 http://myexternalip.com/raw`

This returned the eth0 external IP address, however `curl --interface usb0 http://myexternalip.com/raw` did not, curl outputted this instead:

```
curl: (45) bind failed with errno 22: Argument invalide
```

I don't know what to do. :(

Comment: Instead of a second default route, can you use  `route add -net 192.168.42.0 gw 192.168.42.129 usb0`?

Comment: i will try next week, i'm not at home actually. thanks!

Comment: my router is located at 192.168.1.1, what did i do wrong? :( http://pastebin.com/efX2fiAP

Answer (score 1):

You should only have one default route - having more than one can lead to unexplained behavior and a general lack of reliable network connectivity. If you want all traffic going out the usb0 interface, remove the eth0 default route.

Comment: i will try next week, i'm not at home actually. thanks!